# SMTP Send Mail Task Failing

Tags: ssis, smtp

I have already gone through multiple links before posting and it is not a repeat question.I am not pretty sure that i should post it here or on server fault.

I am trying to configure the SMTP email task but running into error mentioned below.
*System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions ipaddress:25*

I also tried to verify using powershell, if the SMTP is fine and below are the results:

1. Using Send-mailmessage : It is working really fine
2. Using Net.Mail.SmtpClient : I could send email to organization email ids but not outside.

Can someone help me understand where exactly the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Antivirus was blocking the requests from SSIS but was allowing the powershell requests.